# Different versions of the Operate method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overloading

I have code that basically is the same, but depending on the number of arguments you provide (up to 5), it will operate with them in a very repetitive way. I have the feeling that this can be optimized in some way, since maintaining and creating all the overloads by hand is a tedious and error-prone task.

The code is 5 versions (overloads) of the `Operate` method. As you can see, it increasingly deal with 2, 3, 4 and 5 arguments (each one is of a given type), so it can adapt from 2 to 5 type arguments.

```
public static Either<ErrorList, TResult> Operate<T1, T2, TResult>(Either<ErrorList, T1> a, Either<ErrorList, T2> b,
    Func<T1, T2, Either<ErrorList, TResult>> onSuccess)
{
    var success = from av in a.RightValue
                  from bv in b.RightValue
                  select onSuccess(av, bv);
    var errorList = new[]
        {
            a.LeftValue,
            b.LeftValue,
        }
        .SelectMany(x => x.ToEnumerable())
        .Aggregate((x, y) => new ErrorList(x.Concat(y)));

    return success.ValueOr(() => errorList);
}

public static Either<ErrorList, TResult> Operate<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Either<ErrorList, T1> a,
    Either<ErrorList, T2> b, Either<ErrorList, T3> c,
    Func<T1, T2, T3, Either<ErrorList, TResult>> onSuccess)
{
    var success =
        from av in a.RightValue
        from bv in b.RightValue
        from cv in c.RightValue
        select onSuccess(av, bv, cv);

    var errorList = new[]
        {
            a.LeftValue,
            b.LeftValue,
            c.LeftValue,
        }
        .SelectMany(x => x.ToEnumerable())
        .Aggregate((x, y) => new ErrorList(x.Concat(y)));

    return success.ValueOr(() => errorList);
}

public static Either<ErrorList, TResult> Operate<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>(Either<ErrorList, T1> a, Either<ErrorList, T2> b, Either<ErrorList, T3> c, Either<ErrorList, T4> d,
    Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, Either<ErrorList, TResult>> onSuccess)
{
    var success = from av in a.RightValue
                  from bv in b.RightValue
                  from cv in c.RightValue
                  from dv in d.RightValue
                  select onSuccess(av, bv, cv, dv);

    var errorList = new[]
        {
            a.LeftValue,
            b.LeftValue,
            c.LeftValue,
            d.LeftValue,
        }
        .SelectMany(x => x.ToEnumerable())
        .Aggregate((x, y) => new ErrorList(x.Concat(y)));

    return success.ValueOr(() => errorList);
}

public static Either<ErrorList, TResult> Operate<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult>(
    Either<ErrorList, T1> a, 
    Either<ErrorList, T2> b, 
    Either<ErrorList, T3> c, 
    Either<ErrorList, T4> d,
    Either<ErrorList, T5> e,
    Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, Either<ErrorList, TResult>> onSuccess)
{
    var success = from av in a.RightValue
        from bv in b.RightValue
        from cv in c.RightValue
        from dv in d.RightValue
        from ev in e.RightValue
        select onSuccess(av, bv, cv, dv, ev);

    var errorList = new[]
        {
            a.LeftValue,
            b.LeftValue,
            c.LeftValue,
            d.LeftValue,
            e.LeftValue,
        }
        .SelectMany(x => x.ToEnumerable())
        .Aggregate((x, y) => new ErrorList(x.Concat(y)));
    
    return success.ValueOr(() => errorList);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this without repeating almost the same code? Imagine that I would like to create another overload for 6, 7, 8... arguments. It can be really tricky and sub-optimal.

Comment: You may use the (generic) [Template Method](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method) design pattern, to concentrate the repeated algorithmic parts in a base class.

Comment: I'd suggest you use a T4 template (.tt file) to generate the overloads. You can have a for loop from 2 up to the number of arguments you need and generate each overload. The T4 template itself might be a bit of work but I think it should be straightforward.

Comment: How do you use this code right now?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to extract the common piece of code into a helper method:

```cs
private static Either<ErrorList, TResult> Operate<TResult>(ErrorList[] errorLists, Either<ErrorList, TResult> success)
{
    var errorList = errorLists
        .SelectMany(x => x.ToEnumerable())
        .Aggregate((x, y) => new ErrorList(x.Concat(y)));

    return success.ValueOr(() => errorList);
}
```

Then you can reduce the overloads' body only to calculate the helpers inputs:

```cs
public static Either<ErrorList, TResult> Operate<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult>(
    Either<ErrorList, T1> a, Either<ErrorList, T2> b, Either<ErrorList, T3> c, Either<ErrorList, T4> d, Either<ErrorList, T5> e,
    Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, Either<ErrorList, TResult>> onSuccess)
  => Operate<TResult>(
    new [] { a.LeftValue, b.LeftValue, c.LeftValue, d.LeftValue, e.LeftValue },
    onSuccess(a.RightValue, b.RightValue, c.RightValue, d.RightValue, e.RightValue));
```